# Cursor often disappearing

Tags: macos, cursor

I remember this issue happening to me since at least High Sierra, maybe Sierra, maybe before.

When switching between spaces my mouse pointer is invisible until I click on the menu bar at the top of the screen.

Doesn't happen all the time, and I don't know how to reproduce or perform it consistently, but when it happens it's really annoying.

How can I stop it from happening?

This is happening a lot more at the moment, I am on macOS 10.14.4, MacBook Pro w/ Retina display Mid-2015